# What is the purpose of AWS Sam local

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Read some docs but I'm still really confused.

Seems like the purpose of Sam local is to be able to test my Lambda is locally right?

well many of my Lambdas invariably need to access a database (Dynamo) maybe some kind of storage (maybe like S3) as well as other services.

How do I do that locally with Sam local? I expect to be able to define a template that spins up a local version of Dynamo and S3 but I don't see any examples.

Is the thing only for the simplest of lamdas? Or is there a mocking strategy with this im missing?

Comment: You should be able to create an `event.json` that can communicate with whatever service triggers the event. 

https://github.com/NZenitram/s3-lambda-html-parser/blob/master/event.json

That link has en example that performs an actual S3 PUTS when I invoke SAM locally. The principal ID has been obfuscated. If you go into the AWS Lambda console you can copy and paste preconfigured test templates from the test drop down on the functions page and get an idea about how they are structured.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock in that case.
Also, in my own experience, making simple script which will package lambda and upload it to AWS with following invocation -- is way more faster (even when lambda with libraries around ~10mb), than spinned up and running aws-sam-local.

Comment: sam local has no native way to mock these services? Creating an event.json is just a test "event" I want to unit test the actual code.

Comment: Sadly, `sam local` only runs lambda parts of the sam specifications.  You can hook up dynamodb etc with dockers manually.